# Im having a hard time of proving two surfaces tangent at a given point

Tags: calculus, vectors, surfaces

Show that the two spheres

$$x^2 +y^2+z^2=a^2$$

$$(x-b)^2+y^2+z^2=(b-a)^2$$

are tangent at the point $(a,0,0)$.
I already obtained the gradients of the two equations which are equal to

$$\nabla f(x,y,z)= <2x, 2y, 2z>$$

$$\nabla g(x,y,z)= <2(x-b),2y,2z>$$

im having a hard time to find the constant multiplier γ
please help me!!!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/588/how-can-i-ask-a-good-question for information on how to attract quality answers. Proper formatting is expected; for information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Substitute $x = a$, $y = z = 0$ into your gradient vectors. If that doesn't help, could you please explain where you're stuck?

Answer (score 0):

In the following equation system if $b=0$, the spheres are same and all points conflict.
$$\begin{array}{lcl}
x^2 +y^2+z^2 & = & a^2  \\
(x-b)^2 +y^2+z^2  & = & (b-a)^2 &
\end{array}$$

So we can take $b \neq 0$. By subtraction of the equations $(x-b)^2 -x^2=(b-a)^2-a^2$ and we yields $2bx=2ab$. Since $b \neq 0$, $x=a$ is unique solution. We put $x=a$ in $x^2 +y^2+z^2  =  a^2$ (or in $(x-b)^2 +y^2+z^2 = (b-a)^2$), we find that $y^2+z^2=0$. Hence $y=z=0$. Since $(x,y,z)=(a,0,0)$ unique solution of the system, the spheres must tangent each other.